# Jar signing timestamp service runtime requirement

Tags: java, security, certificate, timestamping

If I sign a JAR with a timestamp is it a requirement that the timestamp service be accessible at runtime when the JAR is downloaded?

The reason I ask is that the application is used without access to the internet, and is launched via Java Webstart.

As a followup, if timestamp service access is required at runtime, if the certificate is valid (not yet expired) but the timestamp service is not accessible, will my application run or will it be blocked.

Using the latest version of Java 7.

Thanks